# ASP.Net windows authentication seems not working

Tags: windows, authentication

I have a web application with Windows Authentication enabled. It is working only with localhost though I have set Bindings. Ping to IP and hostname returns result.

Any help would be appreciated

Have set authentication to windows and impersonate to true. NTLM has been moved up.
Also tried adding the site to Intranet and Trusted Site list. Windows authentication is enabled in IE as well.

Both the server and client is on the same domain ... in fact it is not at all working in server itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Finally it worked after making changes in registry and restarting the web server!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Answer (score 0):

With the detail you've given it is a bit hard to give concrete advice so I'll give you a method I've used over the years to try and track down where the issues is.

With the current setup put an image on your webserver and try to retrieve it in the browser using the exact address. Do this on the server itself first and if that works then do it on a client machine.
If it works on server but not on client then there could be a client browser issue/a network issue/a dns issue.

If it doesn't work on the server then change the file level and IIS permissions to anonymous for just that image and the folder / website it is in. Then test the URL on the server in a browser and on a client in a browser.
If it works you've got a permissions issue with NTLM.

Hope this helps you narrow things down.
Dorje